# How to register a new type in GType in vala?

Tags: glib, vala

I found some type non listed in the GLib.Type, if I want to create and register an new type in GType, how to implement it?

I mean the integer types are not listed:
https://valadoc.org/gobject-2.0/GLib.Type.html

```
public const Type INT8
public const Type INT16
public const Type INT32
public const Type INT64
public const Type INT128

public const Type UINT8
public const Type UINT16
public const Type UINT32
public const Type UINT64
public const Type UINT128
```

and there are many boxed type not defined in GLib.Type:
https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Boxed-Types.html

Comment: What do you mean by `non listed`? Please give some more detail / show us your code.

Comment: May be that https://gitlab.gnome.org/astavale/vala/commit/cc5588347f7b1efbd522c073b6a79bb6602b771f

Answer (score 1):

`Type.INT64` and `Type.UINT64` are already there. See the [declarations in the `Type` struct in the `gobject-2.0.vapi`](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vala/blob/master/vapi/gobject-2.0.vapi#L607). Adding the other basic types to that VAPI shouldn't be a problem. Submit a pull request to [Vala's GitLab instance](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vala).

The boxed types you list should also be fairly simple to add. You might want to check the C header `glib-object.h` and submit it as a separate commit just in case there is a complication.

It looks like these are pre-defined types used by the GObject runtime type system. New types can be declared separately at runtime and Vala deals with that behind the scenes when you create your own types.